# How to force display contents outside its parent container in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an E-commerce site, I have different categories(phone, computers, etc) and each category has a drop-down box.
My problem is displaying the drop-down contents outside its parent element and still be able to scroll horizontally(overflow-x : auto)
Each time I add an overflow-x:auto;, the drop down list becomes inside of the parent container.

```css
.carte {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: auto;
  /*makes drop down boxes(.innerCart ) not visible*/
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.category {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: visible;
}

.cart {
  position: relative;
}

.outerCart {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 7px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.innerCart {
  display: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #BABABA;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.cart:hover .innerCart {
  display: block;
}

.innerCart p:hover {
  background: #f4f4f9;
  color: rgb(59, 56, 56);
}
```

```html
<div class="carte">
  <div class="category" id="categorny">
    <div class="cart">
      <div class="outerCart">
        <img src="/shop/images/phone-icon.png" class="phoneimage">
        <p>Phones</p>
      </div>
      <div class="innerCart">
        <p onclick="location.href='phones/android/index.html' ">Android</p>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p onclick="location.href='phones/ios/index.html' ">IOS</p>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p onclick="location.href='phones/accessories/index.html' ">Accessories</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
      <div class="outerCart">
        <img src="<?php echo $stream?>/images/computer-icon.png" class="phoneimage">
        <p>Computers</p>
      </div>
      <div class="innerCart">
        <!-DROP DOWN CONTENT FOR COMPUTERS-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
      <div class="outerCart">
        <img src="<?php echo $stream?>/images/electronics-icon.png" class="electronicimage">
        <p>Electronics</p>
      </div>
      <div class="innerCart">
        <!-DROP DOWN CONTENT FOR ELECTRONICS-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
      <div class="outerCart">
        <img src="<?php echo $stream?>/images/fashion-icon.png" class="clothingimage">
        <p>Fashion</p>
      </div>
      <div class="innerCart">
        <!-DROP DOWN CONTENT FOR FASHION-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
      <div class="outerCart">
        <img src="<?php echo $stream?>/images/beauty-icon.png" class="clothingimage">
        <p>Beauty</p>
      </div>
      <div class="innerCart">
        <!-DROP DOWN CONTENT FOR BEAUTY-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
      <div class="outerCart">
        <img src="<?php echo $stream?>/images/vehicle-icon.png" class="vehicleimage">
        <p>Vehicles</p>
      </div>
      <div class="innerCart">
        <!-DROP DOWN CONTENT FOR VEHICLES-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
      <div class="outerCart">
        <img src="<?php echo $stream?>/images/service-icon.png" class="serviceimage">
        <p>Services</p>
      </div>
      <div class="innerCart">
        <!-DROP DOWN CONTENT FOR SERVICES-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
      <div class="outerCart">
        <img src="<?php echo $stream?>/images/house-icon.png" class="houseimage">
        <p>Housing/property</p>
      </div>
      <div class="innerCart">
        <!-DROP DOWN CONTENT FOR PROPERTY->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
      <div class="outerCart">
        <img src="<?php echo $stream?>/images/food-icon.png" class="foodimage">
        <p>Food/bakes</p>
      </div>
      <div class="innerCart">
        <!-DROP DOWN CONTENT FOR FOODS->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
      <div class="outerCart">
        <img src="<?php echo $stream?>/images/pet-icon.png" class="foodimage">
        <p>Livestock/Pets</p>
      </div>
      <div class="innerCart">
        <!-DROP DOWN CONTENT FOR PETS->
      </div>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" id="arrow"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are lots of typo in your css

Comment: I've corrected all

Comment: Please include a [example].